# How to resize texts in all devices?

Tags: html, css

I want to make text to be resize in all devices. It looks good when I view in on my PC but when I view it on my phone, it doesn't fit to the box and overlap with the button above and below

Here is my code

```css
.container-profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay-profile {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  background-color: #008CBA;
}

.container-profile :hover .overlay-profile {
  opacity: 1;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: auto;
  position: inherit;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper bgded; container-profile">
  <div class="container-profile">
    <img src="https://www.kent.ac.uk/sportsciences/employability/images/image-pending.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay-profile">
      <div class="text">
        <p class="text-justify">SCORE (Standing Commitee on Research Exchange) merupakan Organisasi berbentuk Badan Semi Otonom, bersifat Independent dan berstatus sebagai satu-satunya organisasi penelitian mahasiswa Fakultas Kedoktean Universitas Sumatera Utara yang bergerak
          di bidang penelitian dan kelimiahan. Berdiri pada tanggal 19 Agustus 2003 dan berkedudukan di Medan, Kampus FK USU. Semenjak berdiri, SCORE bertujuan untuk mewujudkan dan menumbuhkan budaya ilmiah di lingkungan Kampus Fakultas Kedoktean Universitas
          Sumatera Utara. SCORE tergabung dalam Badan Analisis dan Pengembangan Ilmiah Nasional Ikatan Senat Mahasiswa Kedokteran Indonesia (BAPIN ISMKI).</p>
        <br>
        <p style="font-style: italic; text-align: center;">Scripta Manent Verba Volent <br> "Yang tertulis akan abadi, dan yang terkatakan akan binasa"</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Click [here](http://www.scorepemafkusu.com) for example

Comment: Consider using bootstrap's grid layout to set the space which your elements can take on different sized devices. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/. Also to space your elements you can try flexbox. Number of tutorials available online for both and can be used together.

Comment: Set default `font-size` on root (html) then other font-sizes in `rem` at each breakpoint of `media queries` change the `font-size` of root and all the `font-size`s in `rem` will change relevant to the root. This is far from a perfect solution (hence it's a comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just spend some time to play with [`Viewport-percentage`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths)

viewport-percentage values are:

- `vw` (the viewport width)
- `vh` (the viewport height)
- `vi` (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's inline axis)
- `vb` (1% of the viewport size in the direction of the root element's block axis)
- `vmin` (the smaller of `vw` or `vh`)
- `vmax` (the larger or `vw` or `vh`)

hope your problem will be solve if you use `vw` like this:

```
.text {
    font-size: 5vw;  // OR whatever value you need
}
```

Comment: thanks for your advice. It solves when i added a new 1`vw` `font-size`

Comment: glad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Just need to add a metadata in your HTML file like

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

This will adjust your font size in device.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the media queries to get the different sizes fonts to suit the device you are using.

[more about media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Answer (score 1):

Set .logoHeader div height auto.

```
.logoHeader{
    height: auto;
    min-height: 120px;
}
```

If That's not the problem. you can check Nitheesh's and Al Amin's answer.